# Infer collective prices based on individual prices

Tags: microeconomics, model, prediction

Given a neighborhood with $m$ trash removal companies currently serving $n$ neighbors, each paying $p_m$ for the service, how would an economist calculate an expected price, $p_e$, in the event that the neighborhood collectivized the purchase to:

- Reduce cost for trash company (denser pickups, one bill)
- Reduce the number of trash trucks going through neighborhood

i.e., neighborhood accepts bids from $m$ trash companies to serve the neighborhood for the period of 1 year. Assume that the neighborhood is large enough that the truck's capacity doesn't impact the calculation.

I hope that this example is trivial enough that I might understand it, but the answer is complicated enough that I might automate and grow it to examine an entire sector of an economy. I know that the specifics of the contract, neighborhood and company will impact the price, so if new variables need to be introduced to adequately describe the system, by all means.

Comment: The question in this form is too vague to be answerable. Whether or how much the neighborhood gains from collectivizing the purchase and what price it could achieve depends strongly on the cost structure of the trash removal companies and on the prevailing market structure.